# How can I use Marionette in my typescript project with require.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, typescript, marionette, amd

I'm having some error as below;

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Marionette is not defined
```

I am using the following `files(main.ts->config, app.ts-> first class of the app)` with using the grunt watch *(typescript compile with --module amd)*. My question is refer to my error problem, How can I import Marionette `(modules/marionette.d.ts)` so that I could use `Marionette.Application();` and configure my application?

main.ts;

```
// Require JS all the things
/// <reference path="modules/require.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="modules/marionette.d.ts" />

require.config({
    basePath: 'assets/js',
    paths : {
        backbone : 'vendor/backbone',
        underscore : 'vendor/underscore',
        jquery : 'vendor/jquery',
        marionette : 'vendor/backbone.marionette',
        debug : 'vendor/ba-debug',
        handlebars: 'vendor/handlebars'
    },
    shim : {
        jquery : {
          exports : 'jQuery'
        },
        underscore : {
          exports : '_'
        },
        backbone : {
          deps : ['jquery', 'underscore'],
          exports : 'Backbone'
        },
        marionette : {
          deps : ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
          exports : 'Marionette'
        },
        handlebars: {
            exports:'Handlebars'
        },
        debug: {
          exports: 'debug'
        }
    }
});

// initalise the app
// load AMD module app.ts (compiled to app.js) , tsc --module AMD main.ts
// and include shims $, _, Backbone

require(['backbone', 'app','routers/router','routers/controller', 'debug', 'jquery','underscore'], (Backbone, App, CustomRouter, AppController, debug, $, _ ) => {

  debug.log('starting app');


  App.on('initialize:after', function(options) {
        if (Backbone.history) {
            Backbone.history.start();
        }

  });

  var router = new CustomRouter({
      controller : new AppController()
  });


  App.start();
});
```

app.ts;

```
/// <reference path="modules/marionette.d.ts" />
var app:any = new Marionette.Application();

app.addRegions({
   header : '#Header',
   // main   : CustomRegion.extend({el: '#main'})
   main  : '#Main'
});

app.addInitializer(function() {


});
```

Thanks

Comment: I like your name. My name is Tank. Gokhan Tank.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell requireJS to load `marionette` before it starts running app.js.

This is done using amd-dependency:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="marionette"/>
```

You can see a sample here : https://github.com/basarat/typescript-amd/blob/master/app/scripts/app.ts
Along with the video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AGQpv0MKsA

Comment: It worked. I havent seen about this amd-dependency feature anywhere? 

So when I use "export" key with --module AMD compile, It creates the define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) { ... } 

and additionally when I add the amd-dependency, It creates define(["require", "exports", "marionette"], function(require, exports) { .. } It works great but I just wonder why doesnt it add Marionette parameter inside the function closure ? Thanks

Comment: Since it doesn't want to name it for you. You could have something like `path="somefolder/marionette"` which you want referenced as `marionette`. You can do that manually using a require call e.g https://github.com/basarat/typescript-amd/blob/master/app/scripts/app.ts#L18

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Yeap, I've tried it but It was giving me an error like "Uncaught Error: Module name "backbone" has not been loaded yet for context: _" I couldn't figure out how to do it work

Comment: Then add `/// <amd-dependency path="backbone"/>`

Answer (score -1):

I'm using this as a reference and it works perfectly [Structuring Backbone with RequireJS and Marionette](https://github.com/davidsulc/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette) . Hope this help you to solve your issue! :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment but the question is about the usage of require.js in Typescript, not Javascript.